Native federation - Angular 17
I am working with micro frontends using native federation in Angular 17. I have encountered the issue that the 'app-loading-bar' component is not displayed in the shell, as I have instantiated it in the main component and it is not necessary to route it. My configuration is as follows:
//federation.manifest.json
{ "mfe1": "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.json" }

//federation.config.js
const { withNativeFederation, shareAll } = require('@angular-architects/native-federation/config');

module.exports = withNativeFederation({

shared: {
...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
},

skip: [
'rxjs/ajax',
'rxjs/fetch',
'rxjs/testing',
'rxjs/webSocket',
// Add further packages you don't need at runtime
]

});

//app.config.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormExampleComponent } from './main/components/form-example/form-example.component';
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/native-federation';

export const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', component: FormExampleComponent},
{
path: 'flights',
loadComponent: () => loadRemoteModule('mfe1', './Component').then((m) => m.RequestGuarenteeComponent),
}

] ;

configuration in mfe1 :
//federation.config.js
const { withNativeFederation, shareAll } = require('@angular-architects/native-federation/config');

module.exports = withNativeFederation({

name: 'mfe1',

exposes: {
'./Component': './src/app/main/guarentee-plataform/request-guarentee/request-guarentee.component.ts',
'./loader':'./src/app/common/components/loading-bar/loading-bar.component.ts'
},

shared: {
...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
},

skip: [
'rxjs/ajax',
'rxjs/fetch',
'rxjs/testing',
'rxjs/webSocket',
// Add further packages you don't need at runtime
]

});


// app.component.html in mfe1
<router-outlet> <app-loading-bar></app-loading-bar> <router-outlet/>

manage to show the component

Could you please show the your project hierarchy, or the repo?
